# euclid's 13th proposition

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Euclid's 13th Proposition goes as :

**Proposition 13.**
 If a straight-line stood on a(nother) straight-line
 makes angles, it will certainly either make two rightangles,
or (angles whose sum is) equal to two rightangles.

I am annoyed because I find some text book treats this Proposition as an AXIOM.

It confused me a lot. I need an expert comment.

Answer (score 0):

Axioms are pedagogy: a means of exposition. The same theory can be presented in many different forms. Axiomness isn't an intrinsic quality of a statement, so some presentations may have different axioms than others.

(axioms also have technical value, but I believe that's unrelated to this question: e.g. you can show that something is a model of a theory by showing it satisfies a choice of axioms for the theory)

Comment: My question is simple. Whether Proposition 13 of Euclid is a proposition or an axiom ?

Comment: @saibal: It's an axiom in and only if you decide to include it in an axiomatization. It's *always* a theorem. (note that axioms *are* always theorems: as they are trivial to prove a statement using itself)